# Keeping lightbox thumbnails always evenly spaced within a div

Tags: html, css, image, lightbox

Im looking for a way to make the lightbox thumbnails I am using stay evenly spaced within a div, and also be evenly spaced when one of them drops down due to window resizing.

Comment: you should share some working Demo, so everyone can easily answered it. Right now this question is hit & trial procedure based.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to center them horizontally try creating this class then adding it into the markup.

```
.lbcenter{
   margin-left:auto;
   margin-right:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping each thumbnail img with a css rule that gives them the desired amount of padding.

```
thumbnail{
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}
```